# Object is currently in use elsewhere

Tags: c#, locking

I'm getting this error, and it looks like it's because the same Bitmap object is being accessed by different threads. However I am using locks everywhere with it.

```
public class MySingleInstanceClass
{
    private Object locker = new Object();

    private Bitmap myImage = new Bitmap(100, 100);

    public Bitmap MyImage
    {
        get
        {
            lock (locker)
                return myImage;
        }
        private set
        {
            lock (locker)
                myImage = value;
        }
    }

    private void Refresh()
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            var g = Graphics.FromImage(myImage);
            // do more processing
        }
    }
}
```

Class `MySingleInstanceClass` will have only one instance. Calls to `MyImage` and `Refresh()` may come from different threads. As far as I understand, the code inside `lock(locker)` will not be executed until it's finished in another thread, but I still get the error. Can anyone point a flaw in the code?

Exception looks like that:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
>
> Error: Object is currently in use elsewhere.
>
> at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(Image image)
>
> at (points to the line containing var g = Graphics.FromImage(myImage);)

Comment: the lock inside the getter/setter appears pointless....

Comment: what do you think that you achieve with locking the getter (and the private setter?) of MyImage? I am just thinking out loud so don't assume I have the solution, but wouldn't it make more sense if the locking behaviour was in the consuming class of this class?

Comment: @MitchWheat well, I am making sure that a thread that calls MyImage waits until the thread that calls Refresh() finishes the block of code there, otherwise I will return myImage before it's finished processing.  Do you think I don't need it? Why?

Comment: Can you show exception message with inner exception if any?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan It's basically what is in the question title; I added it at the bottom.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the `locker` object is not static; thus every new instance creates its own locker; you need to create `locker` as static in order to prevent access from other threads if using multiple objects.

```
private static Object locker = new Object();
```

For single object scenario, using a non static class level variable as a locker is proper. If you are employing this scenario I feel that the implementation of Singleton has some problems.

UPDATE:

```
public sealed class MySingleInstanceClass
{
    private static volatile MySingleInstanceClass instance;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();
    private Bitmap myImage;

    private MySingleInstanceClass() 
    {
        myImage = new Bitmap(100, 100);
    }

    public static MySingleInstanceClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                        instance = new MySingleInstanceClass();
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }  

    public Bitmap MyImage
    {
        get
        {
            lock (syncRoot)
                return myImage;
        }
        private set
        {
            lock (syncRoot)
                myImage = value;
        }
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            var g = Graphics.FromImage(myImage);
            // do more processing
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There is only single instance, and so there is only one locker (the class is singletone)

Comment: then the code you have provided does not match with the question?

Comment: @MitchWheat Can you explain why non-static object cant be used to lock access to instance members?

Comment: @daryal Does it really matter how I implement the singletone for fixing this error?

Comment: @daryal Can you explain what will happened if i will remove `static` keyword from declaration of `syncRoot` object in both `singletion` and `multi-instance` scenario?

Comment: @daryal Thanks for the great example of thread-safe singletone, but as I said I only have one instance of the class (I'm not using singletonne in its standard implementation because framework I'm using sadly disallows static fields). It looks like the problem is solved by returning a copy of the Bitmap.

Comment: @GeorgiiOleinikov Any other option other than cloning the bitmap..I am not allowed to clone

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't matter whether the object that is locked is static or not. The problem is that the `lock(locker)` inside the getter method unlocks as soon as the bitmap is returned. The returned reference to the bitmap is not protected by the lock and can be modified at the same time as a call to `Refresh` occurs.

One possible solution would be to lock on the bitmap itself but that can introduce deadlocks if not done carefully.

Comment: What if I return the copy of the bitmap in the getter?

Comment: If you replace the `return myImage` with `return (Bitmap)myImage.Clone()` you will also avoid the error. But without seeing the code that uses MySingleInstanceClass it is hard to say if that would be a good solution.

Comment: It appears I can't directly add comment to the other offered solution MySingleInstanceClass so I write it here instead. Imagine 2 threads. Thread 1 just repeatedly calls `MySingleInstanceClass.Instance.Refresh()`. Thread 2 calls `MySingleInstanceClass.Instance.MyImage` and then modifies the returned Bitmap. This will cause the exception that you showed us in your question.

Answer (score 1):

In my app the best solution was:

- copy dir with files to another, tmp. catalog (with guid name)
- use tmp files per user
- delete tmp catalog with files in it

In my app there is:

- each request is 1 min long
- max users is 120 (intranet application)
- nobody want to wait 5-10 min for raport to generate

Copy few files add about 0,01-0,2 sek. for each request, is better that static lock on all app and user don't neet to wait 10 min for raport to generate (10 users click generate button in same moment).

```
        private void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
    {
        // Get the subdirectories for the specified directory.
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

        if (!dir.Exists)
        {
            throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
                "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
                + sourceDirName);
        }

        // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it. 
        if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
        }

        // Get the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
            file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
        }

        // If copying subdirectories, copy them and their contents to new location. 
        if (copySubDirs)
        {
            foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
            {
                string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
                DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
            }
        }
    }


        private void DeleteReportExecutionDirectory(string dirPath)
    {
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo downloadedMessageInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
        foreach (FileInfo file in downloadedMessageInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            file.Delete();
        }
        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in downloadedMessageInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            dir.Delete(true);
        }
        downloadedMessageInfo.Delete();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can clone that image before send it to method

```
                Image newimg = (Image)img.Clone();
```