# C# Draw on a PictureBox

Tags: c#, multithreading, image

Suppose i have an PictureBox with image assigned to it, and i just want to draw a smaller bitmap above it.

This is my code:

```
 Bitmap a = Getimage();//just a small function generates a new image.
 Bitmap f = (Bitmap) pictureBox1.Image;//getting the picturebox image.
 Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(f);
 g.DrawImage(a,150,200);//draws a on f at (150,200).
 PictureBox1.Image=f;
```

However, in my program it runs on a loop in a seperated thread, so im getting an Error:

> Object is in use elsewhere

Is there any way to draw directly to the `Picturebox` itself? instead of getting it's bitmap and draw, and assign again? Or at least how may i solve the above exception?

Thanks.

Comment: Call `Control.Invoke` on the `PictureBox` and also make sure you dispose `Graphics` and `Bitmap`

Comment: @Bauss still getting the same error- used this: `pictureBox1.Invoke(new Action(()=>   pictureBox1.Image =  f));`

Comment: `Image` is not thread-safe. You have to `lock` and use image at one `Thread` at the same time: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14660815/213550

Comment: @VMAtm  alright.. but im always use one thread only..

Comment: You said that this is being run in separate thread. So you have 2 threads simultaneously use this `Image`: UI and your background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will help you

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        new Thread(MyDraw).Start();
    }

    private void MyDraw()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Invoke(new Action(DrawItem));
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    private void DrawItem()
    {
        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
        {
            graphics.DrawString("Hello", new Font("Arial", 20), Brushes.Yellow, PointF.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This defeats the purpose a new thread though, considering the drawing still happens on the UI thread. The drawing should happen in a seperate thread and then the data should be passed to the UI thread.

Comment: The sample code is useful if you have a thread that creates some data, and then draws that data on the bitmap in the UI thread. If you want the actuall drawing to happen outside UI thread, you need to create a new `Bitmap`, draw on it, save it as a Stream in memory, then reacreate the Bitmap in UI thread from the Stream, although, I suspect just recreating will be slower than just drawing in UI thread. In most cases, drawing in UI thread is fast enoughg to not cause noticeable UI freezes.

Comment: @Alireza im getting the exception `object is in use elsewhere` when creating the graphics.... why the hell is this?! :(

Comment: Maybe its the second time of running the loop. In the first run, you create a `Graphics` object and not release it. In the second run, you can't create a new `Graphics` on the same Bitmap which is in use by the first `Graphics`